# A Weird Sequence

Tags: pattern, number-sequence, sequence, number-property

Today, I was in Rome for a vacation. The most peculiar thing happened. A gnome walked up to me. Uttering no words, it handed me a slip of paper.

> 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 5, 5, 9, 4, ?

Naturally, I was confused. I tried to solve it, but I couldn't. What number is `?`?

---

The gnome came up to me again, after I had spent considerable effort on the problem, and had gotten nowhere. It handed me this note (**hint**):

> ```
>               Hi
>              Weird
>            Isn't it?
>            Try harder
>      You'll get it, I'm sure
>  Keep traveling this road; observe
> ```

Comment: I know of a sequence that closely matches this one, although slightly different. Is the third term here definitely correct?

Comment: @hexomino Yes, it definitely is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Had the gnome walked all the way from [Pisa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonardo_da_Pisa), by any chance?

The sequence seems to be counting

> the number of individual straight pen strokes needed to write the numbers of the [Fibonacci sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) in [Roman numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals).

Like so

> ```
>  0, 1, 1,  2,   3, 2,    5,    5,   5,     9,  4, ?
>   , I, I, II, III, V, VIII, XIII, XXI, XXXIV, LV, ?
> ```

If this is the case, then the next number would be

> **11**, corresponding to the number of straight pen strokes needed to write `LXXXIX`.

Comment: Ah, I was way off, +1